# FastAPI dynamically generate Sub-APIs

Tags: fastapi

I would like to create a modular app, in which different sub-APIs would be available.
Those API could be enabled/disabled by configuration.

Here's the FastAPI example as shown in their doc :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/app")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World from main app"}


subapi = FastAPI()

@subapi.get("/sub")
def read_sub():
    return {"message": "Hello World from sub API"}


app.mount("/subapi", subapi)
```

Here's what I would like to do :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/app")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World from main app"}

endpoints = ['subapi1', 'subapi2, 'somethingelse']

for e in endpoints:
    x = FastAPI()

    @x.get("/sub")
    def read_sub():
        return {"message": "Hello World from the "+x.root_path+" sub API"}

    app.mount("/"+e, x)
```

so that it would have this behaviour :

```
GET /subapi1/sub
{"message": "Hello World from the subapi1 sub API"}

GET /subapi2/sub
{"message": "Hello World from the subapi2 sub API"}

GET /somethingelse/sub
{"message": "Hello World from the somethingelse sub API"}
```

But obviously, the dynamic decorator syntax doesn't work, and the `root_path` property is not available either.
Is there any way to achieve what I would like to do ? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78113096/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an APIRouter instance and include it under as many prefixes as you want:

```py
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI, APIRouter
import uvicorn


subapi = APIRouter()

@subapi.get('')
async def subapi_get(request: Request):
    return {'i_am': request.url.path}


app = FastAPI()


endpoints = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')

for endpoint in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'):
    app.include_router(subapi, prefix=f'/{endpoint}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app='foo:app', reload=True, debug=True)
```

This will answer with the current path under `/foo`, `/bar` and `/baz`.